# Insert a records count into a different table

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert-into

I need to write the count of all records in one table into another. I am using an INSET INTO statement, it seems pretty straightforward. Access returns that I am making a syntax mistake. Here is my query:

```
   INSERT INTO tblA (Field1)
   VALUES (SELECT COUNT(tblB.ID) FROM tblB);
```

What is the problem here? Access documentation says you are allowed to give a query as argument for VALUES. Is it the aggregation that Access doesn't like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `INSERT INTO...SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO tblA (Field1)
SELECT COUNT(tblB.ID) FROM tblB
```

Answer (score 9):

I would do it with `insert . . . select` as Tim recommends.  But, I want to explain what is wrong with your syntax.

The syntax for `insert . . . values` is:

```
insert into tblA(field1)
    values ( . . . );
```

Notice the parentheses.  In addition, a subquery always needs to have *its own* parentheses.  So, to make your version work, you need an extra set of parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO tblA (Field1)
    VALUES ( (SELECT COUNT(tblB.ID) FROM tblB) );
```

Comment: I still get an error while trying to simply add the parenthesis. It's probably an Access limitation. Thanks for pointing the error out.

Answer (score 0):

## this the easy way we can use COALESCE, i hope it's usefull

```
SELECT
    table1.id,
    COALESCE(table2_count, 0) AS table2_count,
    COALESCE(table3_count, 0) AS table3_count
FROM users
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS table2_count
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY id
) table2_counts ON table2_counts.id = table1.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS table3_count
    FROM table3
    GROUP BY id
) table3_counts ON table3_counts.id = table1.id
```

Comment: `COALESCE` is not supported in Access SQL.